# How to apply a function in a where clause with doctrine 1.2

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

Imagine i want to search a phone number in my DB but they are saved with different formats

Exemple : 
12345678
13.36.15.36
13.654.365

What is the best way with doctrine to find a given phone.

I wish i could do something like this

```
Doctrine_Core::getTable('user')->create('u')->where(str_replace('.', '', u.phone) = ?, $phone)
```

Is there some kind of way to achieve this ?

Comment: Using any function to skip the formatting during the search introduces a large overhead to the query.  Can you not store them in a standard format (even as an additional)?

Comment: In this example, we could, but in my case, i can't

Comment: I think you would need to either use the [`Doctrine_RawSql` object](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/native-sql/en) or write an extension to add the function, it is not supported by default.  Alternatively, process the data server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried using sql functions in the select method like concat and date_format. I don't see why replace wouldn't work.

Try this:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
     ->select("REPLACE(telnumber,'.','') as tel")
     ->from("user")
     ->where('tel = ?',123456);
```

To get your results in array format:

```
$q->execute(array(),Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mySQL [Replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace):

```
SELECT replace(`telnumber`, '.', '') as 'telnumbers' FROM `yourtable` where `telnumbers`=123456
```

Where `telnumber` is the field holding the telephone numbers, `yourtable` is the name of your table, and `123456` is the number you're looking for..

You can nest REPLACE statements if you wish to remove other characters from the telephone number field before searching, and/or also use `telnumbers LIKE "%123456%"` or similar...

Comment: Thank you but can we do the same thing with doctrine ?